# Clear Child Scope in ng-include on Template Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-include

I have HTML Code like:

```
<select ng-model="category" ng-change="categoryChanged(category)" class="form-control"
     data-ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories">
     <option value="">All Categories</option>
</select>
<div ng-include="subCategoryTemplate"></div>
```

My Controller Code is:

```
$scope.categoryChanged= function (category) {
    if (category) {
        templateService.getSubCategoryTemplate({ categoryId: category.id }).$promise.then(
            function (model) {
                if (model) {
                    $scope.subCategoryTemplate = model.subCategoryTemplate;//Here I am getting on Template Path from the server
                    $scope.carCompanies = model.carCompanies;
                }
            },
            function (error) {

            });
    }

$scope.filer = function () {

        alert($scope.selectedCarCompany.id);
    }
};
```

Template HTML is:

```
<select ng-model="$parent.selectedCarCompany" class="form-control"
        data-ng-options="carCompany as carCompany.name for carCompany in carCompanies">
    <option value="">All Car Companies</option>
</select>
```

My Scenarios is:
For the first time, When `categoryChanged` is called, `ng-include` loads the template and user selects a `carCompany` `$scope`'s property `selectedCarCompany` is set. But even if the user change the category from the dropdown and `categoryChanged` event changes the template to some other view, still $scope's`selectedCarCompany` have the value from the previously selected template. Is there a way to clear the `$scope` on change of ng-include template?

Comment: how do you change the scope of your template?

Comment: I don't change $parent.selectedCarCompany, I read on click of button in $scope.filer function. I change category from the category dropdown which change ng-include which loads different template than car company template.

Comment: On categoryChanged, I change the path of my template.

Comment: why are you changing the template and not the data passed to the template?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: you have different templates for each element from your select?

Comment: Yes! Each category dropdown item has different template.